# JUnit 5 @MethodSource in nested class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5, parameterized

I am working with JUnit 5 and I want to create parameterized tests in a nested class. For example:

```java
class CardTest {
    @Nested
    class Cost {
        Stream<Arguments> cards() {
            return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(Card.common(0, Color.RED), 0),
                /** Other Data **/
                Arguments.of(Card.choseColor(), 50)
            );
        }
        @MethodSource("cards")
        @ParameterizedTest
        void cardCost(Card card, int cost) {
            assertThat(card.cost()).isEqualTo(cost);
        }
    }
    /** Some other nested classes or simple methods **/
}
```

The problem is `@MethodSource` required that specified method must be `static`. But Java does not allow static methods in non-static inner classes. If I declare the class **Cost** `static` then it won't be collected by JUnit.

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 53):

**@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)**

You may select the "single test instance per class" mode annotating the nested class with `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`:

```
class ColorTest {

    @Nested
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class Inner {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("colors")
        void blue(Color color, int blue) {
            Assertions.assertEquals(color.getBlue(), blue);
        }

        Stream<Arguments> colors() {
            return Stream.of(
                    Arguments.of(Color.BLACK, 0),
                    Arguments.of(Color.GRAY, 128),
                    Arguments.of(Color.BLUE, 255)
            );
        }
    }

}
```

When using this mode, a new test instance will be created once per test class.

**ArgumentsProvider**

Or you may switch from a `MethodSource` to an `ArgumentsProvider`.

I modified your example to see if it compiles and runs locally:

```
class ColorTest {

    static class Blues implements ArgumentsProvider {

        @Override
        public Stream<Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) {
            return Stream.of(
                    Arguments.of(Color.BLACK, 0),
                    Arguments.of(Color.GRAY, 128),
                    Arguments.of(Color.BLUE, 255)
            );
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class Inner {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @ArgumentsSource(Blues.class)
        void blue(Color color, int blue) {
            Assertions.assertEquals(color.getBlue(), blue);
        }
    }

}
```

More details at http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

Comment: I think in this case test data and the test are logically spitted. I don't sure that is a good idea.

Comment: Added second solution that a) allows a non-static method source and b) ties the test data and logic in-place. Caveat: when using this mode, a new test instance will be created once per test class.

Comment: It annoys me that Java won't just let me have a static method in my inner non-static class. Seems like a bit of an arbitrary decision to me.

Comment: @Hakanai as of Java 16 it is possible to have static methods in non-static inner classes.

Comment: @ValerijDobler nice, maybe I'll get to use that some day soon.

Answer (score 24):

Another variation based on [JUnit 5.2.0](http://Factory%20methods%20in%20external%20classes%20must%20be%20referenced%20by%20fully%20qualified%20method%20name%20%E2%80%94%20for%20example,%20com.example.StringsProviders#blankStrings.) is this.

```
class ColorTest {

public static Stream<Arguments> provideColors() {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(Color.BLACK, 0),
            Arguments.of(Color.GRAY, 128),
            Arguments.of(Color.BLUE, 255)
    );
}

@Nested
class Inner {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("com.domain.ColorTest#provideColors")
    void blue(Color color, int blue) {
        Assertions.assertEquals(color.getBlue(), blue);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It works well. To note that it will work even if the method provideColors  will be private (and static).

Answer (score 8):

A bit late to this game, but...

You can implement the provider, as a static, in the outer class. Then, in @MethodSource, you simply need to provide the fully qualified name of the parameter (i.e., com.biz.pckg#colors).

This is documented in the JUnit user guide.

Comment: Yes, this answers the original question. A more complete example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975605/how-to-use-methodsource-defined-in-other-class-in-junit-5

Basically, in addition to the fqcn, you need to know that you use # not .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for **Kotlin**:

```kotlin
class MyContainerTest {

    @Nested
    @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    inner class MyNestedTest {
 
        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("generateArgs")
        fun `Test should work`(
            argument: String
        ) {
            // Use the argument
        }

        private fun generateArgs() = listOf(
            "abc",
            "xyz",
            "1234"
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have several nesting, you can provide the fully qualified path to the static method. E.g.

```java
package com.foo.bar;

class MyRootTestClass {

  @Nested
  class Nested1 {
  
    @Nested
    class Nested2 {
      
      public static Stream<Arguments> getArgs() {
        return Stream.of(
                        Arguments.of("hello", 123),
                        Arguments.of("World", 456)
                );
      }       

      @ParameterizedTest
      @MethodSource("com.foo.bar.MyRootTestClass" +
                    "$Nested1" +
                    "$Nested2#getArgs")
      void myTest(String text, Integer int) {
      
      }

    } // Nested1

  } // Nested2

} // MyRootTestClass
```

Pay attention to the nested classes separator '$' in the path and the method separator '#'